Tubing in exterior wall in Illinois
As I am upgrading my vanity in upstairs bathroom I had to move my pipes to exterior walls. I also had plumbing and ventilation there so I had to put them quite close to the outside wall. I insulated them with rubber insulation - do you think it is enough? Or shall I also run heat tape? Thanks

Section 890.1210  Design of a Building Water Distribution System
a)         Design and Installation.  ... No distribution pipe or pipes shall be installed or permitted outside of a building or in an exterior wall or attic unless the pipe is protected from freezing. https://www.ilga.gov/commission/jcar/admincode/077/077008900I12100R.html

Is insulation enough to protect from freezing?
